# Resizing with single value after padsquare(from augly) gives RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, image-augmentation

I am facing a bit of a bizzare problem: I have a bunch of different sized images and I am trying to train+infer on these, and I have the following example transform code:

```
import augly.image as imaugs
import augly.utils as utils

        self.infer_transform = transforms.Compose([
            imaugs.PadSquare(p=1),
            transforms.Resize([384], interpolation=torchvision.transforms.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
```

When I use a batchsize >1 I get thrown this:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 384, 384] at entry 0 and [3, 385, 384] at entry 3
```

I find this really bizarre, since, after PadSquare, when I resize using a single int, it should give me a square image back - but it seems like it does not... why is this? is this a bug? It almost seems like some round-off error (got [3, 384, 384] at entry 0 and [3, 385, 384]).

Hoever, if I do this:

```
        self.infer_transform = transforms.Compose([
            imaugs.PadSquare(p=1),
            transforms.Resize((384,384), interpolation=torchvision.transforms.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
```

it works fine...

What is the reason behind this? I am perplexed! When I try out sample images in say colab, they seem to have the same size...

Comment: I am not sure where you are pulling this function from `PadSquare`, I can't seem to find it in the docs. Which version of `imaugs` are you using?

Comment: ah its from facebook's augly! updated code above.

Comment: What is your image resolution before applying the transform?

Comment: @Ivan: they vary - this is why I padsquare them first..

Comment: Did you try to find an instance (and its dimensions) where it fails?

Comment: @Ivan hmm no, I had a dataloader which loads like 150k images... :(

Comment: You should do so in order to pinpoint the issue.